# Can I install the latest version of phpMyAdmin and use it with WampServer?

Tags: phpmyadmin, wampserver

I have WampServer 2.0 with phpMyAdmin 3.2.0.1. The latest version of phpMyAdmin is 3.3.8.1.

Can I download the latest version of phpMyAdmin and use it with WampServer?

The reason I want to do that is that in phpMyAdmin 3.2.0.1 the relationship lines between tables do not appear in Internet Explorer 8 (even though they do appear in Firefox and Chrome). I want to see if the latest version has that fixed.

Thanks.

UPDATE:
The lines show up in compatibility view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I download the latest version of phpMyAdmin and use it with WampServer?

Sure. You can even install it in a separate directory and have it point at the same database as the other version.

Comment: I succesfully downloaded the latest phpMyAdmin version to C:>wamp>apps, next to the old version, changed C:>wamp>alias>phpmyadmin.conf to point to the new folder. The latest version has the same problem.

Comment: @Geoffrey too bad! I saw a PDF view mentioned, maybe that helps?

Answer (score 30):

Follow these steps

1. Download the latest version of PHPMyAdmin at http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php. 
   Note: If you are running PHP version 5.3 you should download the latest PHPMyAdmin version 3.x, otherwise download the latest PHPMyAdmin version 2.x
2. Go to `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.2.0.1\` and copy out the config.inc.php file to somewhere safe.  You are doing this in case you have a password protected MySQL install or specific MySQL options set you to want to keep.
3. Create folders in `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.2.5\`
4. Copy the contents of the unzipped folder (not the folder) into the `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.2.5\` directory.
5. Then copy back the config.inc.php into  C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.2.5\ you copied earlier.
6. Go to `C:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf`. Change following:

   ```
   Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpMyAdmin-3.2.0.1/"

   <Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpMyAdmin-3.2.0.1/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
   ```

   to:

   ```
   Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.2.5/"

   <Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.2.5/">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride all
       Order Deny,Allow
       Deny from all
       Allow from 127.0.0.1
   </Directory>
   ```
7. Restart wamp and start up PHPMyAdmin in your browser and see if it works.

PHPMyAdmin has been upgraded

Comment: Thanks mate. Its the best answer.

Comment: Actually, you should quite Wamp Server completely and start it again. this worked for me rather than restarting services.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely!

I covered in detail [how to upgrade phpMyAdmin in WAMP](http://john-dugan.com/upgrade-phpmyadmin-wamp/) with a series of screenshots in a blog post. Below are the basic steps.

1. Download the [most recent stable version of phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php).
2. Extract the contents of the download to the apps directory inside your WAMP root, typically `c:/wamp/apps`.
3. Copy the `config.inc.php` configuration file from the current version of phpMyAdmin to the new version.
4. Update the `phpmyadmin.conf` configuration file located in the *alias* directory, typically `c:/wamp/alias`. Point the `Alias` and `<Directory>` paths to your new phpMyAdmin directory.
5. Update the `wampmanager.conf` configuration file located in the WAMP root directory.
6. Last but not least, **Restart All Services** in WAMP (assuming WAMP is running), and login to your upgraded phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

you can update easily
->just open the link download the version you need and run
[Wampserver homepage](http://wampserver.aviatechno.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, phpMyAdmin on my side could not work with PHP version 8 using WampServer. All i had to do is the following steps:

1. Download the latest version of **phpMyAdmin** [here](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/news/)
2. Extract the downloaded archive into `.../wamp/apps`
3. Copy the `...wamp/apps/phpMyAdmin5.1.1/config.inc.php` from the old version of phpMyAdmin and pasted into the newest version I downloaded
4. Change phpMyAdmin path in `...wamp/alias/phpmyadmin.conf` to the latest version I downloaded
5. Quit the **Wamp Server** and start it again
6. Click the **Wamp Server** icon on the **system tray** and click `phpMyAdmin 5.1.1` or any previous version, you should see phpMyAdmin page in your web browser

That is all I had to do to add a compatible version of **phpMyAdmin** that would properly work with **PHP 8**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Wamp, I know it might be very late, but non of the above solutions worked for me. So I tried to find it myself, and this is the only way it worked (in config/database.php):

> ```
> 'mysql' => [
>             'driver' => 'mysql',
>             'dump' => env('APP_ENV') == 'local'  ? [
>                 'dump_binary_path' => 'D:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.36\bin',
>                 'use_single_transaction',
>                 'timeout' => 60 * 5, // 5 minute timeout
>             ] : [],
>             ...
>            ],
> ```

You have to find where your wamp files locate, and put the path of your mySql path and version to 'dump_binary_path'.